# Getting error when trying to close and then re-open Tkinter 'Frame' widget

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to open a frame container widget with a listbox widget, a "Select" button, and a "Close" button. The intent is to allow creation of a custom list from a master list of all items available to the listbox widget. The frame/listbox widgets will be needed to be accessed many times but it should only popup when needed.

I have tried the place.forget method on the 'Close' button, but further attempts to reopen the widget create additional instance of the frame and its child widgets. I also tried the place.destroy method, but gives an error when attempting to reopen the frame widget.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk() 
root.geometry('1080x768')
mainCanvas = Canvas(root, height=768,width=1080)
mainCanvas.pack()
popup = Frame(root, bd=3, relief=RAISED)

def addNew(): 
    popup.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.2, anchor=CENTER)

    scrollbar = Scrollbar(popup, orient=VERTICAL)   
    Lb1 = Listbox(popup, height=3, yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
    scrollbar.config(command=Lb1.yview)
    scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
    Lb1.insert(1, "item one")
    Lb1.insert(2, "item two")
    Lb1.pack()

    addbutton = Button(popup, text="Choose list item")
    addbutton.pack()

    cancelbutton = Button(popup, text="Done", command=popup.destroy)
    cancelbutton.pack()

addItem = Button(mainCanvas, text="+", width=3, height=1, 
command=addNew)
addItem.grid(row=20, column=0) 

root.mainloop()
```

> Exception in Tkinter callback Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1542, in **call**
>       return self.func(*args)   File "C:\Users\Home\Desktop\stackoverflow.py", line 11, in addNew
>       popup.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.2, anchor=CENTER)   File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1991, in place_configure
>       + self._options(cnf, kw)) TclError: bad window path name ".46913176"

Comment: You should create the frame only once and then use `place(...)` to show it and `place_forget()` to hide it.

Comment: Also it is not a good idea to combine different layout managers, you are using `pack()`, `place()`, and `grid()`. You should choose one of them and use it throughout.

Comment: @probat: it's perfectly fine to use more than one in an application, and arguably it's  a best practice to do so. The only time they shouldn't be mixed is when using both `pack` and `place` on widgets that have a common master.

Comment: @probat I changed them all to pack() with same result. Destroy() completely destroys the widget permanently, and attempts to recall it cause the error reported above. Forget() causes the widget to be hidden(desired behavior) but then when called again causes the original instance and a duplicate to be created every time another pack() is called.

Comment: @Manny see Bryan Oakley's comment regarding using more than one layout manager.

Comment: The layout manager has absolutely nothing to do with the issue I am having. I changed the code above to use the pack() method in every instance, just to eliminate that as a possibility.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it! I moved the popup frame declaration inside the addNew() function and used the popup.destroy method, and voila! Thanks for the feedback!